# Why is the second Windows partition mounted under /host

Tags: partitioning, wubi, mountpoint

Probably I could read it somewhere, but couldn't find anywhere.

In Windows 7, I have had two partitions ("Disk C" and "Disk D"). After installing dual-boot Ubuntu, I can access disk C under /media/Windows, which is what I expect: disks are mounted under /media. My two external hard drives are also found there. However, disk D is mysteriously mounted as /host. Why? Can I change it (to put disk D under /media as well)?

With MountManager 0.2.6: both disks C and D are ntfs-3g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mounting to /host because your windows "D:" partition is "hosting" your root.disk file, which contains your root filesystem (since you are using Wubi, your root filesystem is stored in a file on an ntfs partition).

1: No, you can't reasonably change this, though you can make a symlink from /media/foo to /host

2: Wubi does not currently support this configuration (having the root.disk on a partition other than "C:") properly and therefore **Your Ubuntu install will fail to boot at some point in the future.** Likely it will happen when you try to upgrade to the next major release of Ubuntu, but it could happen sooner.

I recommend that you back up all the data currently in your Wubi install, uninstall Wubi via Windows Add/Remove programs, and install Ubuntu in a normal dual boot configuration by booting from an Ubuntu LiveCD/USB and running the installer there.