# Accessing Windows partition inside Wubi

Tags: partitioning, wubi

My hard disk crashed and I had to reinstall Ubuntu.  I dual booted it using Wubi and I installed it in C: partition.  When I boot into Ubuntu, I can't see my partition (The partition where Windows is installed) but I can see my second partition, D:.  Do I need to mount the partition?

Comment: Is it not mounted under /host as per these question/answers?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/20535/why-i-cant-access-partition-on-which-i-have-installed-it and http://askubuntu.com/questions/32650/why-is-the-second-windows-partition-mounted-under-host

Answer (score 6):

The Windows partition where you installed Wubi is available as /host within Ubuntu (Places > Computer > File System > Host) All the other partitions will be available under Places > Removable Media

See [WUBI FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) for additional tips.

Comment: Oh I see... Thanks! BTW is there anyway to mount it as a drive in Ubuntu?

Comment: It is already "mounted", Wubi installs Ubuntu in file (a virtual drive) so the Windows drive has to be mounted for Ubuntu to boot.