# How can I acess all Windows 7 files from a Wubi Ubuntu installation?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, wubi, files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing Windows partition inside Wubi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86586/accessing-windows-partition-inside-wubi)

I don't want to install any programs or anything. I just want to know if its possible. If so, how? I am dual booting, using WUBI for the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Windows partition where you installed Wubi is available as /host within Ubuntu (Places > Computer > File System > Host) All the other partitions will be available under Places > Removable Media

Taken from the [wubi wiki guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_access_the_Windows_drives.3F).