# Not recognizing partitioned hard-drive

Tags: gnome, partitioning, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing Windows partition inside Wubi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86586/accessing-windows-partition-inside-wubi)

Right, here's the situation. I'm experimenting for the first time, so please bear with me. Google has shown no such solutions.

Lenovo W500 laptop. I have my primary hard drive, which is where I keep windows and my windows applications. I also have a secondary hard drive in the cd bay of my laptop. This is where I keep my windows files, and where I told Wubi to put Ubuntu.

Boot up Ubuntu. I like it. Now I want to listen to music and mess around with my pictures. Except Ubuntu refuses to recognize the hard drive that it is (supposedly) on.

Solutions?

Thanks

Thanks Uri.
for others: files are found in /host under system files.

Comment: the Windows partitions will be available within the directories /host and /media.

Answer (score 0):

First up I have no experience of Wubi, so I don't know your context.

Are you saying the from within Ubuntu you can't see any filesystems at all? Or can it not see your windows partition? If thats the case what version of windows / what partitioning & drives are you expecting to see?. Where is the media you are trying to mess about with?

If you can bring up a terminal in Ubuntu, you can see the partitions Ubuntu know about (but that may not be mounted) by running `sudo fdisk -l` or `cat /proc/partitions`

Comment: Alright. I ran the sudo fdisk command. It clearly recognizes that there is a drive there. Now my question is how do I get Ubuntu to view its contents?