# How do I access a partition with Ubuntu (installed with wubi)

Tags: partitioning, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing Windows partition inside Wubi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86586/accessing-windows-partition-inside-wubi)

Okay, so I have two different partitions in windows, C:\ and E:. I installed Ubuntu (via Wubi) on the E:\ partition.

How would I access the other partition (C:)?

Cheers!

Comment: See here:

[http://askubuntu.com/questions/86586/accessing-windows-partition-inside-wubi][1]



  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/86586/accessing-windows-partition-inside-wubi

Answer (score 1):

Being that you installed Ubuntu using Wubi, you can access your C:\ drive by changing directories to `/host`  from the command line issue the following command:

`cd /host`

Under Nautilus File Manager you can click on `File Systems` on the left side and then click on your `host` folder.

Comment: /host shows me the E:\ partition, not the C:\ partition?

Answer (score 0):

It should be within your 'Home Folder' under 'Devices'.

You can mount and unmout other partitions there.