# Can I transfer Files from my Windows to my Wubi installation?

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing Windows partition inside Wubi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86586/accessing-windows-partition-inside-wubi)

Is there any way to share files between two partitions??