# Do I need to make a separate partition when installing via Wubi?

Tags: installation, partitioning, wubi

I am using Wubi. Do I need to make a separate partition for Ubuntu? The last time I tried this, it made a folder called `root` on my drive and I could not access any files on that drive within Ubuntu.

Comment: "a separate partition for ubuntu?"- No." I could not access any files on that drive within ubuntu."- You can access the Windows files by going to the /host folder once you booted into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you are using Wubi (the Windows installer) to install Ubuntu in Windows, you don't need to do any repartitioning. Partitioning your drive is only required if you plan on installing Ubuntu alongside Windows via the LiveCD/USB method. Wubi installs Ubuntu in such a way that it is more like a Windows program instead of a standalone OS with its own space.

If you need to access your Windows files in Ubuntu if you installed it using Wubi, see [Accessing Windows partition inside Wubi](https://askubuntu.com/q/86586/18612).

For more information on Wubi in general, see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can access it. However, I'd recommend installing it on a small partition of about 20GB.

It will be relatively hassle free (unless you like tinkering with the system).

Answer (score 0):

you should do it in windows . if you will do it in linux , maybe can be a problem. [Disk Manage Windows](http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/windows-7-partition-manager/windows-7-disk-manager.htm) . after that you can install ubuntu . and you should mount windows disk to ubuntu